# Type narrowing doesn't work when a record defined with rest field

Tags: types, type-conversion, ballerina

```php
import ballerina/io;

type Vehicle record {|
    string mode;
    string color;
    string make;
    string ...; // rest field
|};

type AeroPlance record {|
    *Vehicle;
    string noOfEngines;
|};

type Helicopter record {|
    *Vehicle;
    string noOfRotors;
|};

public function main(string[] args) {
    
    AeroPlance|Helicopter flight = getFlight();
    if (flight is AeroPlance) {
        printAeroPlance(flight);
    } else {
        printHelicopter(flight);
    }
}

function getFlight() returns AeroPlance|Helicopter {
    return {mode:"Air", color:"Red", "make":  "Boeing", noOfEngines:"2"};
}

function printAeroPlance(AeroPlance aeroPlance) {
    io:println("AeroPlance:", aeroPlance);
}

function printHelicopter(Helicopter helicopter) {
    io:println("Helicopter: ", helicopter);
}
```

In the above code, type narrowing doesn't work as expected when the `Vehicle` record is defined with a rest field.  I'm getting the following compilation error.

```
ERROR [b.bal:(26:25,26:31)] incompatible types: expected 'Helicopter', found '(AeroPlance|Helicopter)'
```

However, this works when the rest field is removed from the `Vehicle` record. What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of how typing and type narrowing is defined at the moment with open records (`Vehicle` is an open record, and therefore the `AeroPlane` and `Helicopter` records are also open). Although the jBallerina implementation doesn't allow it, since the records are open and mutable. the specification says a value of a type like

```php
type AeroPlaneOrHelicopter record {|
    *Vehicle;
    string noOfRotors?;
    string noOfEngines?;
|};
```

is valid for `AeroPlane|Helicopter`.

Therefore, the type cannot be narrowed to `Helicopter` in the else block.
If the values were closed or immutable, narrowing would work as expected in the sample.

```php
(AeroPlane|Helicopter) & readonly flight = getFlight().cloneReadOnly();
if flight is AeroPlane {
    printAeroPlane(flight);
} else {
    printHelicopter(flight);
}
```